# Read data from smartcard - pyscard

Tags: contactless-smartcard, pyscard

I'm trying to read data from a "MIFARE Classic 4K - emulated (6212 Classic), Nokia" card with an ACS ACR122U reader.

The sector I need to read is number 18, the Key A is A0A1A2A3A4A5 (I can read it with my smartphone).
Nonetheless, I cannot load the key to the reader nor authenticate.

I managed to get the UID, the reader and the ATR. But I'm mysing something when I try to read a sector.

Edit: I managed to read another card with the same code (but another key). With that card I receive 90 00 with the right key, and 63 00 with a wrong one. But with this card... nothing.

Edit 2:
As far as I have read, it may be a problem with automatic protocol activation. How can I set the layer to read MIFARE Classic memory area?